# Select within audio element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I created a `select` element to choose different songs.

Is it possible to add the `select` element inside an `audio` element?

For example beside the `Play Icon` or  instead of the `Download Icon`.

[image]

Or, if it isn't possible, can i somehow make it look like they are the same element?

**Update**

What i tried so far:

```
<audio>
  <source src="audio/song1.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
  <select>
     <option value="Song1">Song 1</option>
     <option value="Song2">Song 2</option>
  </select>
</audio>
```

and

```
<li class="nav_audio">
    <select>
        <option value="Song1">Song 1</option>
        <option value="Song2">Song 2</option>
    </select>
    <audio controls="" autoplay="" preload="metadata" onloadstart="this.volume=0.25">
        <source src="audio/Song2.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
        <select>
            <option value="Song1">Song 1</option>
            <option value="Song2">Song 2</option>
        </select>
    </audio>
</li>
```

Comment: You can use CSS to do whatever you want.

Comment: Please give us an example so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: ok i will update my question

Comment: Please see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/YVMvGO). Is this along the lines of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to become more familiar with CSS and it's capabilities. I with the code you posted above I just added some CSS to the `li` and the `select` like so:

```css
.nav_audio  {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.nav_audio select {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 7.5px 15px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  background: #fafafa;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav_audio">
  <select>
    <option value="Song1">Song 1</option>
    <option value="Song2">Song 2</option>
  </select>
  <audio controls="" autoplay="" preload="metadata" onloadstart="this.volume=0.25">
    <source src="audio/Song2.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</li>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain a little more in detail.
Also, no you cannot put a `select` tag inside of an `audio` tag. It will not render.